# Angular 2 error 'Illegal constructor'

Tags: angular

I have been stuck on this error for quite sometime and I can't seem to find any reference to it online. There is no line number or reference as to what is actually wrong. `Illegal Constructor` seems so generic, I am not sure how to work with this. any help would be much appreciated.

**here is the error image**
[image]

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import Channelservice = require("../services/channel.service");
import {ChannelEvent} from "../services/channel.service";
import ChannelConfig = Channelservice.ChannelConfig;
import ChannelService = Channelservice.ChannelService;
import SignalrWindow = Channelservice.SignalrWindow;
import './rxjs-operators';

class Notification {
    Id: number;
    NotificationType: string;
    Message: string;
    Exception: string;
    User: string;
    TimeStamp: string;
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: './random.html',
    styleUrls: ['./random.css'],
    providers: [ChannelService, SignalrWindow],
})
export class GasTroubleComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() eventName: string;
    @Input() apiUrl: string;
    timeStamp: string;

    messages = "";

    private channel = "tasks";

    constructor(
        private http: Http,
       private channelService: ChannelService
    ) {

   }

    ngOnInit() {


        this.channelService.sub(this.channel).subscribe(
            (x: ChannelEvent) => {
                switch (x.name) {
                    case this.eventName: { this.appendStatusUpdate(x); }
            }
        },
        (error: any) => {
            console.warn("Attempt to join channel failed!", error);
        }
    )
  }

   private appendStatusUpdate(ev: Channelservice.ChannelEvent): void {

    this.timeStamp = `${ev.data.TimeStamp}`;
    this.timeStamp = "Hello";
 }


  callApi() {
      return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((message: string) => { console.log(message); });
   }
};
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the same SignalrWindow. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: We did not. I am sorry. The team ended up rebuilding the application.

Comment: I actually got a solution to this last night. If I remember correctly, it was because I hadn't included the SignalR files in index.html. But there were a few other issues I fixed last night while trying to get SignalR to work, so it could have been something else. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem,  mine was simple

I didn't close the brackets and yours also seems to be the same problem

You have an extra closing bracket at the end """""};"""""